# convert array to string java

Tags: java, arrays, string

Given an array of numbers (integers) how would I go about converting it to a string.

I am from JS so in we normally do :

```
[1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5].join(separator)
```

But Java doesn't seem to do that.

I tried :

```
 array.join(" ")
```

But that throws an error on that it cannot find symbol.

---

Here is the code :

```
class Conv {
    public static String findOut(int[] arr) {
        return arr.join(" ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't call methods that don't exist, and don't make up methods that "seem" right. Look at the API.

Comment: `java.util.Arrays.toString(...)`

Comment: Stream.of(arr).collect(Collectors.joining(", ")); This will add ", " as separator.

Comment: Please explain how my comment was rude. You're coding by making wild guesses, and I am suggesting that you don't do that. Please consider following the advice.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels : how is this even related to what you linked ? I don't see how it explains the question ?

Comment: @Aominè : Thanks

Comment: @D.B. : Thanks. I understand. Will remember this advise for the next time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no `join` method on arrays, instead you can use the stream API's [`joining`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining-java.lang.CharSequence-) collector:

```
Arrays.stream(arr)
      .mapToObj(Integer::toString)
      .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
```

Comment: Thanks, So I am guessing I need to import `Java.util.arrays` ?

Comment: @MuhammadSalman you need two imports, `import java.util.*;` and `import java.util.stream.*;`

Comment: Thanks, I am new to Java So don't know about how this works. Thanks

Comment: Hi, When I try to use this, It gives an error : `error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to String`

Comment: @MuhammadSalman isn't `arr` an `int[]` as shown in your post?

Comment: Yes, It is an `int[]`

Comment: @MuhammadSalman then it should work. the problem is elsewhere I am afraid.

Comment: Nevermind, It was a mistake on my part, thanks

Answer (score 3):

### Arrays#toString

Java does not provide a `join` method for arrays. Utility methods can be found in the `Arrays` class. For example `Arrays.toString(values)` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(int%5B%5D))) which returns a `String` in the following format:

```
[1, 5, 15, 2]
```

So

```
String result = Arrays.toString(values);
```

---

### StringJoiner

However, you explicitly want the following format:

```
1 5 15 2
```

Therefore, use the `StringJoiner` class ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html)):

```
StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(" ");
for (int value : values) {
    sj.add(value);
}
String result = sj.toString();
```

---

### Stream API

Or use the Stream API ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html)) to achieve the same result but in a more functional-style:

```
String result = Arrays.stream(values)  // IntStream
    .mapToObj(Integer::toString)       // Stream<String>
    .collect(Collectors.joining(" ");  // String
```

Comment: another option would be `Arrays.toString(arr)
                     .replaceAll("\\[|]", "")
                     .replace(",", " ");` or `String.join(" ", IntStream.of(arr)
                    .mapToObj(Integer::toString).collect(Collectors.toList()));`. Though the best approach i believe is the `joining` collector you're using ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
    String out = "";
    for(int i = arr.length){
        out = out+arr[i];
    }
```

I think that is what you want

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Arrays.toString(int[] a)` method.

```
int[] a = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
String b = Arrays.toString(a);
System.out.println(b);
```

It will print `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

Later you can modify the string for what you want.

Don't forget to import java.util.Arrays.

[You can see it at the java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(int[]))

Answer (score 0):

Bit late to the party here, but in case you're stuck on a pre 1.8 version of java (`stream`, `StringJoiner` etc only exist since 1.8), you can just loop through your array and append to a `String`. I put in a ternary operator to not add the space at the end as I assume you don't want that:

```
String result = "";
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    result += (i == arr.length - 1) ? arr[i] : arr[i] + " ";
}
```